# wordpress dropdown menu muti level styling

Tags: html, css, wordpress

so i have a html menu drop down and i want to convert it to wordpress menu. i have three sub menus inside the main menu, this is my code :

```
        <ul class="main-menu-links">

            <div class="sidebar-logo">
                <span class="logo">CodingLab</span>
                <i class="fas fa-times close-2"></i>
            </div>
           
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Video</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Sport</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                <li class="li-class"><a href="#">Technonlogy</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu-2">
                        <li><a href="#">sub-menu-2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">sub-menu-2</a>
                            <ul class="sub-menu-3">
                                <li><a href="#">sub-menu-3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">sub-menu-3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">sub-menu-3</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">sub-menu-2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                
                </li>
            </ul></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sport</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Technonlogy</a></li>
        </ul>
```

and the css :

```
.main-menu-links li:hover .sub-menu{
    display: block;
 }
.sub-menu{
    border-top: 2px solid #0072dd;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 999;
   display: none;
   box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);
   background: linear-gradient(to right,#001e3b,#171717);
 }
 .sub-menu li{
    width: 180px;
    position: relative;
 }
 .sub-menu ul{
     top: 0;
     left: 100%;
    border-top: 2px solid #0072dd;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 1000;
   display: none;
   box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);
   background: linear-gradient(to right,#001e3b,#171717);
 }

 .sub-menu ul li{
    width: 180px;
 }
 .main-menu-links  .sub-menu ul li:hover .sub-menu-3{
    display: block;
 }
 .main-menu-links .sub-menu li:hover .sub-menu-2{
    display: block;
 }
 .sub-menu-3{
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
   border-top: 2px solid #0072dd;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right,#001e3b,#171717);
}
.sub-menu-3 li{
   width: 180px;
}
```

when i convert the code to wordpress menu :

```
<?php 
    wp_nav_menu(
    array(
    'theme_location'    => 'menu-1', 
    'items_wrap'        => '<ul class="main-menu-links">%3$s</ul>',
        ) );
?>
```

and the result when i inspect the wordpress output :

```
"menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-has-children menu-item-32"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/category/tech/">tech</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-81"><a href="#">sub menu</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-82"><a href="#">sub menu 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
```

all my sub menus with sub-menu class there is no sub-menu-2 or sub-menu-3 i want to fix the probleme please. the idea is creating muti drop down menu and styling the sub menus with a deffirents css classes .

probleme picture :

[the probleme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ye4Nc.png)

that's what i want :
[the solution but is just html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7S79.png)

Answer (score 0):

Edit : ok after a lot of research i find the solution with just css :

```
.main-menu-links-left ul ul {
    display: none;
    float: none;
    top: 30px;
    z-index: 3000;
    background: linear-gradient(to right,#001e3b,#171717);
 }

 .main-menu-links-left ul ul li{
    z-index: 3000;
    float: none;
    width: 150px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right,#001e3b,#171717);
    position: relative;
    
 }

 .main-menu-links-left ul ul li a{
    padding: 10px 10px; 
 }

 .main-menu-links-left ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
 }

 .main-menu-links-left ul ul li ul{
    left: 150px;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 5px;

 }
```